# How can I represent a Minkowski diagram for a finite universe in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity

I am having trouble trying to make a minkowski diagram when assuming that space is finite (but time is not), but in the context of special relativity, not general relativity (of which I do not know enough). So I am not really sure if what I am asking makes sense, I am not sure if you can describe a curved finite spacetime without reference to general relativity or something similar. The motivation is trying to see what an observer moving close to c, relative to a reference frame in which most objects are at rest, would see due to length contraction.

My intuition  was that an observer at earth can see objects at rest relative to him up to a given distance, anything more distant in that direction will actually be closer if he watches it in the opposite direction. From his point of view the traveller at close to c will "come back" from the other side after a finite distance and time. From the point of view of the traveler both the travel time and the distance traveled will be shorter.

The problem started when I tried to make a minkowski diagram (let us say space is 1D) and tried to represent a finite space by rolling the piece of paper into a cylinder, so that the x coordinate of the observer at rest, represented by the orthogonal axes, becomes a circle. The problem is that then the x axis of the traveller, which is at an angle, cannot be "closed", at least using a piece of paper.

Thus, is there a proper way to represent this using a 3D surface? is it consistent to talk of finite space but infinite time in a special relativity framework?

Comment: I think you can compactify the spacial dimensions. Then the spacetime becomes a Lorentzian cylinder.

Comment: @XiaoyiJing Thanks! would compactifying be different than rolling the paper into a cylinder? (which as I said, did not seem to work)

Comment: No need to thank me. My comment wasn't helpful anyway. Compactification can be rolling the paper into cylinder. It can also be adding a point (which means you add a circle of infinitely large radius) to make a Riemann sphere. In topology, the latter is called 1-point-compactification. The former is more often used in string theory.